# Initializing the array so that one can find the number of assigned values into the array

Tags: c++, arrays

What is the best way to keep track of the number of assigned elements in predefined C++ arrays?

For example, in the following code, one can easily run a loop till it encounters the first `0` in the array:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 500

int main() {
  int a[MAX] = {};
  a[0] = 1;
  a[1] = 2;
  a[2] = 3;
  // loop
}
```

However, if we consider the following definition:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 500

int main() {
  int a[MAX] = {};
  a[0] = 1;
  a[1] = 0;
  a[2] = 3;
  // loop
}
```

Seeking for the first `0` does not work since there is still a value of `3` after the first `0`.

**My question:** How should I initialize the array so that I would have a "stable" rule of counting the number of assigned values?

Comment: Wrap the array in a structure that also holds a `count` variable.

Comment: Please post the code you are asking about (in this case, the *loops*).

Comment: Use a `std::vector` instead.  `std::vector<int> a; a.reserve(500);` leaves you with 0 elements, but a capacity of 500 so adding to 500 elements wont cause a reallocation.

Comment: @NathanOliver I strongly disagree. There might be 1000 and 1 reasons to prefer static arrays to vectors, and general advice of using `vector` instead of array is misplaced.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use a structure built specifically to support your use case. The very good one I know of is [boost.static_vector](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html).

You can `push`/`pop` elements to/from it, you can explicitly set and query it's size, and all the while the storage is allocated statically.

Comment: I did not downvote of course, but it may be due to my question that is evaluated to be a duplicate and low-quality. Actually, that does not answer my question... Thank you for your answer, anyway!

Comment: @VIVID how does it not answer your question? What is amiss?

Comment: No, I meant the linked post (as a duplicate) not your answer.

Comment: @VIVID I think the duplicate is ill-placed.

Comment: @VIVID I'm with the two of you on that. Good reading, but not related. The Dupe 's going buh-bye.